# Twig dropdown - get user id - "Parameter "id" for route "user_profile" must match "\d+"

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm getting this error:
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "id" for route "user_profile" must match "\d+" ("app.user.id|number_format" given) to generate a corresponding URL.").

and my code is:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('user_profile', {id:'app.user.id|number_format'})}}">{{ app.user.username }}</a>
```

When otputing app.user.username it returns the username, but when I need the number id, it gives me the error.

How can I get it right? Thanks

If I use

```
{% for u in app.user %}

{% endfor %}
```

between the divs
the dropdown stops working,
can I get user number with app.user.id or I need to use for loops?

Comment: `{id:app.user.id|number_format}` __without__ quotes.

Comment: Why would you call number_format on user ID? If user id is 3000 for example - number_format will change it to 3,000 and it also wont match digits only ("\d+")